# Php date localization showing weird characters

Tags: php, date, localization

I'm showing date string in php that is localized. It works fine except on the production server it doesn't show the correct accented characters for French. It does however work correctly on local development machine and staging server. Also for other strings that we provide ourself accented words work and there is no problem. Just for the ones generated with php date

```
http://prntscr.com/4burfd
```

Here are some screenshots of it not working on one server, and working on another server :

[image: Image of it not working]
[image: Image of it working]

Comment: have you tried setting the charset to utf-8?

Comment: If you mean in the html, it is already (and in the browser visiting the page).

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)